# Necesito hacer un cronometro en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy teniendo problemas al hacer mi cronometro, no se si alguien me puede ayudar a hacerlo, soy nuevo en esto y se me hace un poco difícil.

Comment: Hola buen dìa, te  recomiendo dar el tour por SOes y puedas generar una mejor pregunta y esto nos permita poder ayudarte mejor. [tour]

Comment: Para ayudarte mejor, debes mostrar el código que te está dando problemas y decirte en qué puedes mejorarlo.

Answer (score 1):

using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Cronometro
    {
        private Timer Tiempo { get; set; }
        public Double Result { get; set; }

```
    public Cronometro()
    {
        Tiempo.Tick += new EventHandler(Tiempo_Tick);
        Tiempo.Interval = 100;
    }

    void Tiempo_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Result++;
        //cada tick representa 100 milisegundos
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Tiempo.Start();
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        //
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Tiempo.Stop();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            "{0} ms",
            Result);

    }
}
```

}
y luego:

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Cronometro Cronometro { get; set; }

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Cronometro = new Cronometro();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cronometro.Start();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cronometro.Stop();
    }
}
```

}
Para mostrar el resultado utiliza el método Cronometro.ToString();

Comment: Hola Alexis. Aunque es admirable tu deseo de ayudar a otros, cuando una pregunta incluye tan poco detalle que queda muy amplia (como es el caso aquí), es mejor esperar a que se aclare la pregunta antes de contestar. Lo cierto es que ni siquiera sabemos si OP está usando Windows Forms ni qué tipo de cronómetro quiere. Por eso es mejor esperar a que OP agregué su código y sea más específico en su pregunta.

Comment: bueno si es en windows forms application lo intente hacer con labels y me funciono y la manera en que lo hiciste es muy diferente a la mia